# iOS geofencing but GPS indicator still solid

Tags: ios, gps, geofencing

I'm creating a GPS geofencing app for iOS.  One thing I notice is that the GPS indicator in the top right is always solid whenever I run my app.  But after exiting it, it turns back to be a outlined symbol after a few seconds.

I tested the geofence Reminder app that apple has made, and it DOES NOT turn solid when the app is run.

I made sure I did not use the startUpdatingLocation, but only use startMonitoringForRegion.  I don't know what is triggering that solid symbol whenever I launch.

Anyone had the same issue?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you have called method startMonitoringForSignificantChanges and then you never stopped it, call stopMonioring

Answer (score 0):

The same problem was driving me crazy. I then tried to reset my Location & Privacy settings on my iPhone and the problem went away. You can do this by using the Settings app (General -> Reset -> Reset Location & Privacy).

Hope this helps.